# Bind only specific items to gridview from list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list, gridview

I have a `list` where one item have 4 different elements

**Item**

```
Id int
Name String
Value String
Enable bool
```

I want to Bind the `List<item>` to a `gridview`. Currently I am displaying all the items. But I want to display only the `Name` and `Enable` fields only.
What is the easy way of doing this? Without creating new list

Thanks

Comment: depending on your C# version you could use LinQ to accomplish this, but where is this list coming from - because when the list is returned from a datasource like SQL Server you could adjust that query - it's way faster.

Comment: I can use linq.. but I cant changed the data source since it using for other proposes as well. What I can do using linq?

Comment: well basically > create a new list ;-) but with filters

Comment: @riffnl: Seems like you haven't read the question :) I was asking a way without creating a new **list**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GridView.DataSource = from t in yourList
                      select new 
                       {
                       t.Name,
                       t.Enable
                       };
```

Also check out the example to bind [GridView using LINQ](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jayendra/binding-gridview-using-linq/)

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* way?

After binding, hide the columns you don't want to see.

```
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at these LINQ articles to get you in the right direction - what you're actually looking for is LinQ projection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx and use these Basic Query Operations for handling your select: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx